# Suppose $C \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$; prove that $ \sup_{A} C \leq \sup_{B}C$

Tags: order-theory

Suppose $C \subseteq  B$ and $B \subseteq  A$; prove that $$ \sup_{A} C \leq \sup_{B}C$$
That's the problem, let $s= \sup_{A} C$ and $t= \sup_{B}C$, by definition
$(x \leq s)( \forall x \in C) \:$  and $ \: (y \leq t)( \forall y \in B) $

Since $C \subseteq B$, then $(x \leq t)(\forall x \in C)$, so, here my question arises, can I deduce that $ s \leq t $?

Comment: Explaine your notation and do not use symbolic formulas that are not well forned.

Comment: If the class of lower bounds of $B$ in $A$ has a greatest element, then this element is called the greatest lower bound of $B$ in $A$.

Comment: The least upper bound of $B$ in $A$ is also called the supremum of $B$ in $A$ (abbreviated $sup_{A} B$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this exercise is from the book of Pinter?

If you suppose  that $ C \subseteq B $ and $ B \subseteq A $, by transitivity $ C \subseteq B \subseteq A $. Let $ s $ be the minimum upper bound of $ C $ in $ A $ $ (s = \sup_ {A} C )$ i.e $ s \geq x $, $ \forall x \in C $, with $ s \in A $.

Let $ t \geq y $, $ \forall y \in C $, with $ t \in B $, i.e $ t $ is the $ \sup $ of $ C $ in $ B $  $ (t = \sup_ {B} C )$.

Since $ t \in B $ and $ B \subseteq A $, then $ t \in A $, but $ s $ is the minimum upper bound of $ C $ in $ A $, so $ s \leq t $.
$$ \therefore \: \: \: \sup_ {A} C \leq \sup_ {B} C $$